# How do i filter queries?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update the GetCoursesByTeacher method to return a list of the available courses whose teacher's last name equals the passed in lastName parameter value.

-Instantiate an instance of the Context class within a using statement
-Return the results of calling  *Where* and *ToList* on the context's Courses DbSet property

Here's my code

```
 public static List<Course> GetCoursesByTeacher(string lastName)
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
          .Where(cb=> cb.lastName)
              .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a failed to compile error but I don't know where. what am I missing? please help

Comment: I feel that the `cb.lastName` is not a boolean field, am I right ?

Comment: correct it is just a property in a db

Answer (score 1):

`context.Teachers` - your table with data

```
public static List<Course> GetCoursesByTeacher(string lastName)
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        var result = context.Teachers.Where(cb => cb.lastName == lastName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: still seem to having some problems

Comment: Repository.cs(21,30): error CS0411: The type arguments for method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: I'm new to programming and am still learning. what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @user9299960 Try using `List<Teachers> result = ....` instead of `var result = ....`, although this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @MohammadHamoud nope still nothing. I'll have a look later on. Maybe i just need a break

Comment: @user9299960 check table name, check property name (maybe it names `lastName`), check all references are included